# Haskell "Conflicting definitions" when instancing Num

Tags: haskell

I have started to make my type class an instance of Num.

```
data Interval  = IV (Int,Int)
                     | Empty
```

```
instance Num Interval where
  (+) Empty _ = Empty
  (*) Empty _ = Empty
  (+) _ Empty = Empty
  (*) _ Empty = Empty
```

When I test the definitions for `+` and `*` written so far, I always get the error:

```
Conflicting definitions for ‘+’
```

Comment: I don't see how adding an empty interval to a non-empty interval produces an empty interval, nor do I see how you define `*` at all. Note that while not strictly required, it is *expected* that a `Num` instance preserves, among other things, distributivity of `(+)` and `(*)`, that is, `a*(b+c) == a*b + a*c`. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Num.html.

Comment: @chepner A possible way to define the sum of two sets A and B is `{a+b | a in A && b in B}`. If you do that on intervals, and one of them is empty, the result is empty. I am not sure about the properties this sum satisfies, but I believe it is used in some parts of maths.

Comment: Don't do `IV (Int, Int)`. Use `IV Int Int` instead. It will be one less pointer indirection (and one less allocation).

Comment: @chi Going by the name alone, I would be expect `IV (x, y)` to satisfy `x <= y`, `IV (w, x) + IV (y, z) | x == y = IV (w, z)`, `x + Empty = x`, `Empty + y = y`, and `_ + _ = Empty`. I have no idea what it would mean to multiply two intervals.

Comment: @chepner the operations of such intervals are not that simple. Every element of interval A is added to every element of B. The maximal result of the operation becomes the lower bounds and the minimal becomes the upper bounds of the result. So if Emtpy is added, there is no element to do the addition. Therefore there are no elements in the result interval. Its actual just a small part of my current college exercise, I just wanted to minimize the example to show the problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner `data Interval` was given by the professor. But I will remember your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining operations, you need to define one operation completely before starting the next one.

So first define `(+)` and then `(*)` and so on. This should solve your problem.

```
instance Num Interval where
  (+) Empty _ = Empty
  (+) _ Empty = Empty
  (*) Empty _ = Empty
  (*) _ Empty = Empty
```

You will need to define your `IV(Int, Int)`. For the addition `(+)` do not append it to the end but add it to the existing definition of the addition.